mean of all or a subset of columns when subsetting by group using 'j' term in data.table
I have a large data.table where the columns represent many variables (v1... v99) and the ID for each set of variables. I would like to know the mean of each variable for each individual ID.
If this were just a few columns, I would write:
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2),v1=c(1,2,3,4,5),v2=c(2,3,4,5,6)
dt[,.(v1=mean(v1),v2=mean(v2)),by="ID"]

Which gives output:
   ID  v1  v2
1:  1 2.0 3.0
2:  2 4.5 5.5

This is exactly what I want - but I'd like to avoid writing out "v1=mean(v1)" for each of the many many column names (and not have to update my code if the columns change).
I thought perhaps there was a .SD way to do this, eg, something like:
dt[,.SD[max(v1)],by="ID"]

But this is clearly wrong, giving:
> dt[,.SD[max(v1)],by="ID"]
   ID v1 v2
1:  1  3  4
2:  2 NA NA

And I'm thinking (?) it's not just that my syntax is wrong for .SD, it's that all I can do with .SD is tell it which row to pick, not do column based operations.
Short of writing a loop to just write the syntax and then evaluate it using eval (which I could do, but I think is poor form!), is there an efficient way to do this?

like this? dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=ID]

AH - yes, I searched and searched and just didn't find this one somehow. The question/response you pointed to is perfect.
Haven't had a question that did turn out to be a duplicate before, better to delete it to avoid cluttering things up? Something else I do to just mark it answered / point to the other answer?
Thanks!
